# Rendered animation is all white

Tags: rendering

[image]I had made a basic smoke and fluid simulation, and after applying necessary textures, I wanted to save the animation as a video file. After rendering each and every frame (till 150) for around 2 hrs, the animation was finally saved as a video format. Now when I open the video file, all I can see is a white screen, nothing else. Why?
[image]

Edit: Sorry for the late response. Here is the link to my blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mA6utHHBe1YqzVaXOU6mNeSS1KQNfoOO

Even if I render it in PNG format, all the individual PNG files come out to be completely white.[image]

Comment: try rendering a few random frames from the whole video directly to PNG if they have the same result then it is not a video encoding issue.

Comment: Was doing that just now, the result's the same. All the PNG files are white. What's wrong?

Comment: It’s good practice to *always* render to individual images (PNG or EXR) rather than direct to video format. This way you can more easily check progress (by opening individual frames to check the result), you can stop the render and carry on again at the frame you stopped at, or even re-render any sections you aren’t happy with. You can even use the compositor to adjust effects without having to re-render. You then combine the separate images into the final video at the end. It’s impossible to determine what’s gone wrong in your case without more information. Perhaps share your Blend file.

Comment: There is not enough information on your post to understand the problem. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. Add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Here is the link to my blend file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1abTHIhMfwBIQRX4wRcyGx6nWZElsRQ1h